# Not able set document.title after certain interval

Tags: javascript

I will call blinktab() when the app in opened in a tab and the tab is inactive. The tab need to blink title for 2 minutes and then a time out message should appear. meanwhile if the tab got focus the timeout should be cleared. some how i am not able to see the title getting updated in safari. But when i check in console using document.title, then i see updated title.

```
function  blinkTab(message) {
    console.debug("In BlinkTab....");
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 120000){
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        document.title = document.title == message ? ' ' : message;
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.title = 'timed out.';
    }, 120100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var start_blinking = false;
var startTime, message;


blinkTab("message");

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(!start_blinking){
    return;
  }
  document.title = document.title == message ? ' ' : message;
  if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000){
    document.title = 'timed out.';
    console.log("done");
    start_blinking = false; //done blinking
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }

}, 300);


function  blinkTab(message) {
    console.debug("In BlinkTab....");
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
        start_blinking = true;
    message = message;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why?

Comment: I put setInterval in a global scope because if you put it inside a function it will be destroyed as soon as the function end. Means if the interpreter reach the } of a function. Same with setTimeout.

Comment: You should explain that in the answer, comments are transient.

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the global scope, because the call to `clearInterval()` is in the same scope. The variable is saved in the closure.